# python regular expression match valid c expression

Tags: python

Please excuse my poor english. Let me make myself more clear: I have a cpp file, in which it has some text such as:

```
snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"It is python %d,%s",32,"Hello world");

Fmt(100,"This is another %d %s statement",a.getsize().getsize(),"hello")
```

And of course,has some other texts too

What i am trying to do is to use python regular expression to read this file and match these texts and output those match group to another file
I want my regular expression match groups to be:

```
"It is python %d,%s",32,"Hello world"); or
"This is another %d %s statement",a.getsize().getsize(),"hello"
```

I have tried these following regular expression;

```
 pattern1=r"\bsnprintf\s*\(\s*\w+\s*\,.*?(\"(?:.|\n)*?)"\)\;"
 pattern2=r"\bFmt\b\s*\([\s*\d+\s*\]\s*\,\s*(\".*?\))
```

But i got stuck here:
    patter2 is only match group "This is another %d %s statement",a.getsize().  Which is not what i want

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the regular expression you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: I downvoted because no attempt was made.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking for. Are you trying to find strings in argument lists which are followed by other arguments? Are you trying to find any valid C expression, not just those involving strings? Do you understand what the word "expression" means?

Comment: What about `buf,sizeof(buf)` and `100`?

Comment: The set of valid C expressions is not a regular language; there isn't a regular expression to match them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a full generic expression because there is an infinite number of combinations.
Any of the c string specifiers can be used multiple times in any order.
For example; let's take %d and %s :
"%d","%d%s",%d%s%d", you get the point..

You can, however, match a string "" and parse it programmatically or use regex to a subset of the combinations.